# Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:

Tags: java, playframework, yaml, snakeyaml

When I am trying to create an object from a data file, I am getting the following exception while `assest` class is present. I have tried with dum; it was able to dump the data but when I have tried to read same data I am getting the following exception:

```
 [ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:model.Asset; exception=Class not found: model.Asset]
```

File reader:

```
package utill;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import model.*;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;


public class FileReaderUtill  {

    public static List getAssest(String fileName){
        LinkedHashMap<String,Asset> assest=null;
        List<Asset> data= new ArrayList<Asset>();
        try{
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new 
            File("conf/datafile.yaml"));
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

            data=(List<Asset>)yaml.load(input);

            //System.out.println(assest.get("Asset0"));
        }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return data;
    }
}
```

Datafile.yaml

```
- !!model.Asset {cid: null, enable: '1', id: re, internalName: df, name: fd}
- !!model.Asset {cid: null, enable: '0', id: rexz, internalName: dxxf, name: fdxxx}
```

Assest.java

```
package model;


public class Asset  {
    public Asset(){
    }
    public Asset(String id,String cid,String name,String internalName,String enable ){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.internalName=internalName;
        this.enable=enable;
    }

    public String id;
    public String cid;
    public String name;
    public String internalName;
    public String enable;   

}
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Is your Asset class actually in a file called Assest.java?